# problem with LM338 to charge phone

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I used a module using LM338 to charge my phone with 2 pices of AA rechargeable battery
I set it to 5v with 2A current and  connected to phone but the phone was hanging on the same percentage or even lowered!
(the data pins of female usb in unused)
 [image]
please help me
sorry for my bad English

Comment: This is because normally the phone has to negotiate current higher than 0.5A. I guess yours is a cool smartphone that drains more. So it can't negotiate and is starving. Turn it off, so 0.5A will be enough to charge, although slowly.

Comment: my phone's charger output is 5v and 2A, so how phone is charging with it?

Comment: It communicates with the charger. It may be just a pull up/down on one of the USB lines, but i guess it is a real usb communication.

Comment: Do you know how I can increase the current for Samsung Galaxy series?

Comment: I believe that if you short the two data pins in the USB cable (the two middle pins) the Samsung device will see it as a "compatible" device or cable and should charge faster - up to 1 amp rate.  I am not sure if there is something more to do to get it up to the 2 amp "high speed" charge rate

Answer (score 0):

Two rechargeable AA batteries in series will usually provide 2 to 2.5 V, and the regulator you're trying to use is linear, and won't be able to provide a higher voltage than the input. Moreover, from the picture is impossible to understand the way it is connected.

Please post a basic schematic of what you're trying to build.